# On Load Gif Followed by Looping Gif

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to display a gif on site load and then have it change to looping gif afterward. I tried searching StackOverflow with no luck. Any direction on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Below are the two animated icons I created. Their classes distinguish which one is on load and which one is looping.

```css
.on-load-gif, .looping-gif{
        max-width: 335px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        }
    
    
    
.on-load-gif{
    opacity: 1;
   animation: fadeInAnimation ease 3s 
    animation-iteration-count: 1; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-duration: 2s;
} 
  
@keyframes fadeInAnimation { 
    0% { 
        opacity: 1; 
    } 
    100% { 
        opacity: 0; 
     } 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Animation Loop</title>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://rossettibev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/R-Animation-for-Rossetti-on-load.gif" class="on-load-gif"alt="" />
    
    <img src="https://rossettibev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/r-animation.gif" class="looping-gif" alt="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so the first gif appears on the page, then as soon as the page is fully loaded hide that gif and then display the other gif(r-animation.gif)? What else are we waiting for on the page besides what's in the question? I assume using javascript is applicable?

Comment: @jmp Well, the on load gif is not showing up for long enough for the animation on it to play out. Even if I set the duration of the first gif to 50s, it doesn't seem to stay on the page, but rather disappear immediately.